# PHP Session Header does not change URL

Tags: php, redirect, header

A bit of trouble here with getting a header to work properly.

I'm just re-learning PHP and have never used sessions or headers before.

I have a login.php w/ a form that posts to this file:

**checklogin.php**

```
<?php
ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="db"; // Mysql username 
$password="dbpass"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="db"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['username']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['password']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE userName='$myusername' and userPass='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
          session_start();
          $_SESSION['logon'] = true;

// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");
header("location: app.php");
exit();
}
else {
header("location: login.php");
exit();
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Essentially this performs the job, the app.php file is loaded in the browser window, however the URL does not change in the browser window. The URL remains as http://mysite.com/checklogin.php.

What this equates to is that any of my relative links inside of app.php such as app.php#page1 do not because the URL in the browser window is still listed as /checklogin.php

I've searched through dozens of questions here and have come up empty.

I've tried using the entire URL, specifying TRUE and using 302 and 303 in the header, nothing breaks me free of the URL.

Also note, I know jack squat about what ob_start does - this was example code - all I know at this point is if I delete ob_start and its closure at the end it doesn't work.

Comment: Your code is already obsolete. `session_register()` [is deprecated and removed in PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php). You shouldn't be using it in new code and removing it from old code.

Comment: [`mysql_*` functions are officially deprecated, too](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thank @JohnConde - What replaced it? Any tips on how I can re-write this?

Comment: may be there is some error .change error settings ,session_register is depricated

Answer (score 0):

Use Location instead of location in the header() calls.

Also try to put @ in front of session_start(); . Sometimes your session may have already been started, and trying to start it again for a second time, will lead to a notice/warning depending on the php settings on your host, which makes later header() calls invalid if you have no output buffering. Putting @ in front of it silences the notice/warning, so that header() will work again.

If that works (@session_start), you will not need the ob_start() and ob_end_flush() calls, which simply cause buffering of the warnings/notices.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @JohnCode, the code needed an entire re-write to come up to speed w/ PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
header("location: abc.php");
```

to

```
header("Location: abc.php");
```

note the upper case L.

also better to use

```
$_SESSION['myusername']=$myusername;
$_SESSION['mypassword']=$mypassword;
```

than

```
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");
```

because it was Depracated in PHP 5.3 and removed in PHP 5.4
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php